# Confidence Intervals vs. Credible Intervals for statistical inference in linear regression

Tags: bayesian, confidence-interval, inference, credible-interval

Consider the following scenario featuring a linear regression analysis.

In the left panel I have estimated the ordinary least square (OLS) regression line along with the 95% confidence intervals.

In the right panel, the same data are fitted with the Bayesian approach and displayed with corresponding regression line along with the 95% credible interval.

[image]

My questions concern the interpretation of representation of the uncertainty around the regression lines.

**Q1:** In the left panel, is it formally correct to state that the response variable is statistically significantly different from zero for x < 49.42 and values x > 54.01 (i.e. the two values of the predictor at which the confidence intervals don’t touch the 0 line)?

**Q2:** Similarly, is it formally correct to state that the response variable is credibly different from zero between outside the interval 48.74, 54.82 (again, the two values outside which the credible intervals don’t touch the horizontal line)?